# Show two normal rv's are independent from covariance matrix

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, independence

Consider $X\sim N_3(\mu,\Sigma),$ with $\mu^T=(-3,1,4)$ and
$$ \Sigma = \pmatrix{1,&-2,&0\\-2,&5,&0\\0,&0,&2}$$
Are the following independent?

a) $X_1,X_2$

b) $X_1,X_3$

c) $0.5(X_1+X_2)$ and $X_3$

What do I need to do? I know if they are independent then $\Sigma=0$, but the reverse does not hold. What information can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know if they are independent then Σ=0, but the reverse does not hold. What information can I use?

To understand that in a jointly gaussian model the concepts of independence and incorrelation are the same, let's start from the joint density of $X,Y$

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}[\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}-2\rho\frac{(x-\mu_X)}{\sigma_X}\frac{(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_Y}+\frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}]}$$

and set $\rho=0$ that means $X,Y$ incorrelated.

Substituting you immediately get

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sigma_X\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}}\times\frac{1}{\sigma_Y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}}=f_X(x)\times f_Y(y)$$

that means independence.

Answer (score 0):

For jointly normal random variables independence is **equivalent** to covariance being $0$. In each of the three cases it is easy to calculate the covariance, so I will leave the calculation to you.

One more hint: If $a$ and $b$ are constants then  $U$ and $V$ are independent iff $U+a$ and $V+b$ are independent. Hence the answer to this question does not change if you take the mean vector to be $(0,0,0)^{T}$. That will make the answer simpler.

Comment: Just to confirm the covariance can be calculated by $E\left((X_1-\mu_{X_1})(X_2-\mu_{X_2})\right) = E\left((X_1 +3)(X_2-1)\right)$? So this isn't independent?

Comment: I have edited my answer with another hint. Yes, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent. @CCZ23